# Is the function continuous and differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, functions

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} 3x-3 &  x \leq 1 \\ 5x^2+2x-7 & x>1 \end{cases}$$

How do I determine if this function continuous and differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$? I know the solutions, but I don't know how can I get them.

Comment: Polynomial functions are continuous and differentiable.  The only question is what is going on at 1?  g is continuous at x if $g(x) = \lim_\limits{a\to x} g(a)$.    Does the left hand limit equal the right hand limit? $\frac{dg}{dx}$ is defined by a limit.  g is differentiable everywhere if that limit exists at 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check continuity and differentiability of a piece-wise function, you need to check that it is continuous and differentiable on the "pieces" and also where they meet.

So in our case we check the cases $x\in (-\infty, 1]$, $x\in (1, \infty)$ and $x=1$.

1. First we check the interval $(-\infty, 1]$. In this interval $g(x)$ is defined as $g(x)=3x-3$. Since it is a polynomial, it is both continuous and differentiable for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and hence also in $(-\infty, 1]$.
2. Then we check the interval $(1, \infty]$. In this interval $g(x)$ is defined as $g(x)=5x^2+2x-7$. Again, since it is a polynomial, it is both continuous and differentiable for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and hence also on $(1,\infty)$.
3. The last case is at the point $x=1$. Here $g(x)$ is continuous since $\lim_{x\to 1_+}g(x)=\lim_{x\to 1_+}3x-3=0=\lim_{x\to 1_-}5x^2+2x-7=\lim_{x\to 1_-}g(x).$ However it is not differentiable at $x=1$ since the following left and right limits are not equal: 
   $$\begin{array}{rl} \displaystyle{\lim_{h\to 0_-}\frac{g(1+h)-g(1)}{h}} &\displaystyle{=\lim_{h\to 0_-}\frac{3(1+h)-3}{h}=3} \\ \displaystyle{\lim_{h\to 0_+}\frac{g(1+h)-g(1)}{h}} &\displaystyle{=\lim_{h\to 0_+}\frac{(5(1+h)^2+2(1+h)-7)-(5(1)^2+2(1)-7)}{h}}\\ & \displaystyle{= \lim_{h\to 0_+}5h+12}=12\end{array}$$
   Thus $g'(1)$ is not defined, and hence $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=1$.

Answer (score 4):

The function is continuous since $lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}3x-3=lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+}5x^2+2x-7=0$, but is not derivable at $1$ since $lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}(3x-3)'=3$ and $lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+}(5x^2+2x-7)'=12$.

Comment: this technically shows that the function is not continuously differentiable not that the function is not diferentiable, right?

Comment: @clark This shows that it is not differentiable, but it's perhaps a bit subtle: since derivatives (of functions which are pointwise differentiable) necessarily have the intermediate value property, they can never possess jump discontinuities.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Yes you need to use Darboux theorem to conclude non differentiability, since intermediate value property is not something really known in a first calculus course this is a little  bit misleading dont you think?

Comment: @clark True. A solution at the "first calculus course" level would involve taking the limit of the difference quotient rather than the derivative.